# Function application in LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, functional-programming, entity-framework-4.1

We are trying to find a workaround for the issue that the Entity Framework doesn't support non-scalar entities. We are using a particular equality so we try to build an expression that for a given input and a function from that input checks whether that equality holds.

```
    private static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> UserEquals<TElement>(User user, Func<TElement, User> select)
    {
        var userequals = (Expression<Func<User, Boolean>>) (u => u.Source == user.Source && u.UserName == user.UserName);

        //return an Expression that receives an TElement, applies |select| and then passes that result to then `userequals` expression 
        // and uses it's result as return value.
    }
```

I suspect it involves creating a new expression that receives a parameter, but I cannot figure out how to apply the `select` function to that input and then pass the result of that on to the `userequals` expression.

The intended usage is something like:

```
Context.Foo.Where(UserEquals(user, (f => f.User)).Single(f => f.Id == id);
```

Instead of:

```
Context.Foo.Single(f => f.Id == id && f.User.Source == user.Source && f.User.UserName == user.UserName);
```

Ideally we would want to write something like:

```
Context.Foo.Single(f => f.Id == id && f.User.Equals(user))
// or
Context.Foo.Single(f => f.Id == id && f.User == user)
```

Comment: What do you mean by non-scalar entity. The only reference to that I could find was referencing non-scalar variables which is not supported.

Comment: I see now what you're getting at. You should be able to provide an extension which creates the equality test (filter). I'll update my answer after some testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, if I'm understanding you correctly you want to do this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable<Foo> WhereUserEquals(this IQueryable<Foo> source, User user)
{
    // this is your implementation of the entity specific equality test
    return source.Where(x => x.User.Id == user.Id);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<Foo> { new Foo { User = new User { Id = 1, Text = "User" } };

    var user = new User { Id = 1 };

    var q = list.AsQueryable().WhereUserEquals(user);

    foreach (var item in q)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Text);
    }
}
```

Which would allow you to write:

```
Context.Foo.WhereUserEquals(user).Single(f => f.Id == id);
```

If you don't have a base class for accessing the User property of the type Foo you need one such extension for each type, however, that's something which you could quite easily code gen. I don't believe expression tree rewriting will be necessary.

Comment: The problem with this is that we need the Foo, and not the user itself. So I guess that leaves building the expression trees? Or implementing WhereEquals for every entity that contains a User, and then suppose an entity contains two users, you'd need another function. Ideally you would write a selection function for this.

Comment: That's basically what I figured out, but that's still a lot of work for each of the entities we have. A more generic solution would be preferable.

Comment: Have you considered code generation? T4 is built in Visual Studio and it can easily be used to build that kind of boiler plate code (all the metadata is right there in the EF schema). It will also allow you to use a type safe model, the expression tree rewriting can be more dynamic but do you really need to be dynamic here? If you don't want to do code generation then build your EF model so that the User property is inherited in some preferable way, that will allow you to be more generic but other than that, this is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

Are you by any chance looking for [InvokeExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355170.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Could this work ?

```
private static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> UserEquals<TElement>(User user, Expression<Func<TElement, User>> select)
{
    return (Expression<Func<TElement, Boolean>>)(elt => select.Compile()(elt).Source == user.Source && select.Compile()(elt).UserName == user.UserName);
}
```

Currently you have a type mismatch since **select** is invoked nowhere, and thus you have not a `TElement` as input but already an `User`.

Hope this helps...

Comment: With your solution I get the following error: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Which sounds logical since we want to convert to SQL...

Comment: I confess I'm not very used to EF problematics and logic, that's why I gave my answer "as is". As far as I understand the problem, **select** cannot be converted into SQL because of being a pure C# delegate, at least from the compiler's point of view. I edited my answer to make it hopefully more accurate (turning **select** into a lambda).

Comment: The problem is that you cannot convert something like method / function invocation to SQL. The EF translates the LINQ queries to T-SQL queries. So that's the basic issue.

Answer (score 0):

This library solves the problem: http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Microsoft.Linq.Translations

Read more about it here: http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/24/client-side-properties-and-any-remote-linq-provider

I'm relying heavily on this in production.

Comment: How do you propose this problem with Translations? I tried to follow the example. I couldn't get it working because of "The specified type member 'U' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported." (https://gist.github.com/6a226cd2dbe1306a9094) - Also the website is outdated regarding the package, the package doesn't contain Microsoft.Linq.Translations.Auto anymore.